Julia equivalent for MatLab ismembertol
I have two different datasets, say A of dimension (N1,3) and B(N2,3).
I want to identify the rows in A which are approximately equal to some rows in B with tolerances tol = [tol1, tol2, tol3].
In MatLab, a very efficient function does so: ismembertol which returns the row indices of B in idx (in the form of cells) for which a full row in A approximately equals a full row in B within tol
ismatch, idx = ismembertol(A,B, 'DataScale', 1, 'ByRow', true, 'OutputAllIndices', true)

Again, it is very fast in MatLab, taking a few seconds for large datasets (typically, N1 and N2 are of the order of 1 million).
I could not find out any comparable implementation in Julia, knowing that even using multiple threads would be useless to process datasets that large.
Naively, I first used this basic implementation which returns the expected results but performs very bad :
# Function to check if two rows are within given tolerances
function row_within_tolerances(row1, row2, tolerances)
    return all(abs.(row1 .- row2) .<= tolerances)
end
# Define tolerances for each dimension
tolerances = [atol1, atol2, atol3]

# Initialize logical array and cell array to store results
tf = falses(size(A, 1))
loc = Vector{Vector{Int}}(undef, size(A, 1))

# Check each row of A against all rows of B
for i in 1:size(A, 1)
    matching_indices = Int[]
    for j in 1:size(B, 1)
        if row_within_tolerances(A[i, :], B[j, :], tolerances)
            push!(matching_indices, j)
        end
    end
    if !isempty(matching_indices)
        tf[i] = true
        loc[i] = matching_indices
    else
        loc[i] = Int[]
    end
end

# Display the results
println("Logical array indicating matches:")
println(tf)
println("Cell array of indices in B that match each row in A:")
println(loc)


I suspect you want to subtract a single row of A from the entire matrix B, which would mean you only need the outer loop. MATLAB would do this using implicit expansion which is fast, I'm not sure if Julia would do the same. i.e. tf(j)=any(all(abs(A-B(j,:))<=tol,2)),

I tried indeed this approach but even with a little optimization, it takes way too long. As comparison, with 2 arrays, A with 150000 rows and B 2 millions, MatLab takes less than 2 seconds to execute ismembertol while my code takes longer than 30 minutes.

Hello, I am still looking at this question, but there is something not clear.. do you want the ids of the rows of the A matrix or of the B matrix ? First you say "I want to identify _ the rows in A_ which are approximately equal to some rows in B" but then you specify that  "ismembertol returns the row indices of B in idx for which a full row in A approximately equals a full row in B". You can also try discourse.julialang.org, there are very smart people there that are passionate about optimization...

(EDITED)
This function returns the ids of A that have at least one similar row in B:

function approx_similar_rows(m1,m2;tols=fill(0.00001,size(m1,2))) 
    D = size(m1,2)
    matcheses = fill(false,size(m1,1))
    Threads.@threads for i in 1:size(m1,1)
        for j in 1:size(m2,1)
            allsimilar = true
            for d in 1:D
                if abs(m1[i,d] - m2[j,d]) > tols[d]
                    allsimilar = false
                    break
                end
            end
            if  allsimilar
                matcheses[i] = true
                break
            end
        end
    end
    return findall(i -> i == 1, matcheses)
end

Let'c create some sysntetic data, where we have, for selected rows in A, two approximate matches in B:
using Random, Test
Random.seed!(123)
D    = 3
N1   = 150000           
N1eq = 30000
N2   = 2000000

# Creating rows in A that have 2 approximate rows in B
A = rand(N1eq,D)
B = copy(A) .+ (rand() ./ 100000)
B = vcat(B,B)

# Adding the unmatching rows to both A and B...
A = vcat(A,rand(N1-N1eq,D))
A = A[shuffle(1:N1),:]
B = vcat(B,rand(N2-N1eq*2,D))
B = B[shuffle(1:N2),:]

We can then get the ids of A as:
matched_rows = approx_similar_rows(A,B)
@test length(matched_rows) == N1eq

Still, the function above takes 227 seconds on my old laptop (this depends on the number of matches). You can ask on https://discourse.julialang.org for better performance advices. For example, you should be able to get better performances if your data is transposed, i.e. you look for similar columns, as Julia is column major.

Thank you Antonello for your suggestion. However, it assumes that a and b have the same size and it only searches rows with the same index in a and b. In my user case scenario, typically a has 150000 rows and b around 2 millions. rows of a can ("approximately") match several rows in b. I tried with isapprox.(m1[i,:], m2, ...) but the type returned (BitVector) ios incompatible with findall.

Sorry, I will edit my answer. I would still use a bitvector of lenght N1, loop over all rows of A, inner loop over all roes of B or break if a similar is found at a certain point, snd if so set the bitvector for that row of A equal to true. Then I use findall to get the rows of A that have (at least) a duplicate in B. This is general if you don't know the structure of A and B
